# Printing specific row from a table

Tags: python, list

I have a .csv table named data that looks like the following:

| Age | name | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Stan | 9 |
| 4 | Danny | 2 |
| 7 | Elle | 6 |

However, I want to print out a list of names from the table but only if their age is under 10. So in this case `[Danny, Elle]`. Here is what I tried so far

```
if data['Age'] < 10:
     print(data['name'])
```

I get an error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` which I don't understand. It would be helpful to know how to solve this and also understand the error.

Comment: @Andrej's answer is spot on but I wanted to add that you may benefit from reading this page from pandas docs [How do I select a subset of a Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all names where age < 10 you can use boolean-indexing:

```py
mask = df["Age"] < 10
print(df.loc[mask, "name"])
```

Prints:

```
1    Danny
2     Elle
Name: name, dtype: object
```

---

`data['Age'] < 10` evaluates to:

```py
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: Age, dtype: bool
```

so when you do `if data['Age'] < 10:` what should be the result? The error message `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` is telling you that.

Answer (score 2):

If you print `type(data['Age'] < 10)` it will return `pandas.core.series.Series`, this is not a boolean type as you are expecting, it is an object which looks as follows:

```
In [7]: data['Age'] < 10
Out[7]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: Age, dtype: bool
```

You can think of it as a set of boolean elements which are true if the index satisfies the that age < 10 and False otehrwise. You can use these values to retrieve a subset of your table and then print the name column as follows (it will select a subset where the values are True):

```
sub = data[data['Age'] < 10]
print(sub['name'])
```

What the error is telling you is that pandas cannot figure out a boolean value for a complex object such as Series. Put it simply, it is a bunch of indexes, for which one of those are you evaluating it to be true? This is why there are suggestions such as `a.any() or a.all()`, which can be used to convert all the boolean values for each index into a single boolean value (if any of them is true, or if all of them are true, respectively). For example:

```
In [23]: a = data['Age'] < 10

In [24]: print(a)
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: Age, dtype: bool

In [25]: a.any()
Out[25]: True

In [26]: a.all()
Out[26]: False
```

`a.any()` evaluates to true because there is at least one index which is True (2 and 1). `a.all()` evaluates to False because not every index is False (0 is False).